# Pin section headers in eureka formviewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, eureka-forms, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have successfully pinned section headers in UICollectionView by setting `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true` for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and subclassing `UICollectionReusableView`. Is it possible to do something similar when working with Eureka's `FormViewController`? My end goal is to have pinned section headers for each section.

I am using a custom Section by stying UIView like this: (Please note that the constrain block is from Cartography library)

```
private func createSection(title: String) -> Section {
    let section = Section()

    section.header = {
        var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.callback({
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: 39))
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = title
            view.addSubview(label)

            constrain(view, label) { view, label in
                label.left == view.left + 16
                label.bottom == view.bottom - 8
                label.right == view.right - 16
            }
            return view
        }))
        header.height = { 39 }
        return header
    }()

    return section
}
```